# Is there a way to have dynamic commands using SwiftUI commands without fallback to AppKit

Tags: swift, swiftui, command

So far I've tried watching the published value of the App events and updating the `@State` property wrapper, but alas this has no runtime effect on the MenuBar commands.

```
struct MyCommands: Commands {
    
    @State private var isShift = false
    
    var body: some Commands {
        CommandMenu("Things"){
            Button("Thing A\(isShift ? " Shift" : "")"){
                if isShift {
                    print("Thing A Shift")
                } else {
                    print("Thing A")
                }
            }
            .keyboardShortcut(.init(isShift ? "S" : "s"))
            .onReceive(NSApplication.shared.publisher(for: \.currentEvent)) {
                if let evt = $0 {
                    isShift = evt.modifierFlags.contains(.shift)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: 1. are you sure the publisher works? 2. if `.onReceive` doesn't work in a `Commands` struct can you put it in another view and hand the value over to commands?

Comment: btw: dynamic commands in general are definitely possible.

Comment: 1. The events are coming through fine I’ve checked with print statements. 2. If you look, the onRecive is attached to the inner button view and not the opaque  Commands. Btw: I know they’re generally possible in AppKit. I’ve just never seen anybody(even Apple) talk about it with SwiftUI. And updating any kind of state doesn’t seem to trigger any changes in the internal state diff to redraw the CommandsBuilder.

Answer (score 1):

This code just toggles the menu command by selecting it, and this works. So the question remains why the `.onReceive`doesnt do it ...? Even if the @State change wouldn't trigger an immediate redraw in commands, it should still influence the next redraw on selecting the menu again.

```
struct MyCommands: Commands {
    
    @State private var isShift = false
    
    var body: some Commands {
        CommandMenu("Things"){
            Button("Thing A\(isShift ? " Shift" : "")"){
                if isShift {
                    print("Thing A Shift")
                } else {
                    print("Thing A")
                }
                isShift.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by actually taking the advice of ChrisR and moving the event detection to a StateObject and passing value into commands. For some reason the view diff won't change if updating commands from inside itself. Though not entirely sure if this is a bug or a feature.

Note: this is also visually jarring as you can see the menu flash for second when pressing shift, but in AppKit the menu would update instantly without flashing.

```
class EventWatch: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published private(set) var modifiers: EventModifiers = []
    
    private var watch: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
    
    init(){
        NSApplication.shared.publisher(for: \.currentEvent).sink{
            if let event = $0 {
                if event.type == .flagsChanged {
                    self.modifiers = EventModifiers(rawValue: Int(event.modifierFlags.rawValue))
                }
            }
        }.store(in: &watch)
    }
    
}
```

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    
    @StateObject private var evt = EventWatch()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup("MyGroup") {
            Text("My View").frame(minWidth: 1000, minHeight: 600)
        }
        .commands { MyCommands(isShift: evt.modifiers.contains(.shift)) }

    }
}
```